# Moving existing caches to Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

My existing Java application (runs on Liberty) defines a number of caches.
Some caches (hash key/value) can be several GB in size.

I am looking at implementing Redis with clustering and my question is...

Does it make sense to map the existing caches into Redis hashes?
From what I read, Redis can partition by placing different hashes on different
servers, but it wont partition the hash entries, is this correct?

e.g. instead of this...

HSET cache1 cacheid1 "cache value"
HSET cache1 cacheid2 "cache value"
HSET cache2 cacheid3 "cache value"

should I use this instead?

SET cache1_cacheid1 "cache value"
SET cache1_cacheid2 "cache value"
SET cache2_cacheid3 "cache value"

Would the 2nd approach be better for partitioning? or are there other approaches?
Keeping the caches in hashes would make like easier, e.g. when counting elements
or emptying it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Redis can partition by placing different keys on different nodes, but it won't partition the hash entries.

Using a hash per cache is a valid approach.

```
HSET cache1 cacheid1 "cache value" cacheid2 "cache value 2"
```

Note you can do multiple field-value pairs on the same `HSET` command.

This has advantages as you mention, including:

- `HLEN` to count entries
- `HSCAN` to iterates fields, pattern-matching if you want, and getting values with fields. `SCAN` would be over the entire keyspace and only return keys, not values.
- `DEL` or `UNLINK` the whole cache

But it also has cons:

- You cannot set expires on fields on a hash, only on keys.
- Hash can only store binary-safe strings, so you won't be able to use lists, sets, sorted sets or a hash inside the cache hash.

Take a look at [Keys hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags).

This allows you to force keys to end up on the same hash slot. So your second approach can use:

```
MSET {cache1}cacheid1 "cache value" {cache1}cacheid2 "cache value 2"
```

All keys with `{cache1}` in the key name will end up in the same node.